# To open an Image on click over another Image and so on

Tags: html

I want to open an Image on click over another Image and so on.So It's a chain upto 6-7 images. Can somone suggest me how can I implement it.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body style="background:color:red">
    <a href="images/Delivery/2.png">
        <img src="images/Delivery/1.png">
    </a>
</body>
</html>
```

With above mentioned code I am able to open only 2 images. How can I able to access another image on click over "2.png" and so on.

Comment: Please keep in mind that SO is not a code writing service. You should show the code of what you have tried so far to solve this problem and where you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to achive this

```
//Initial image element
<img src="images/Delivery/1.png" />

var imagesToShow=["1.png","2.png","3.png","4.png","5.png","6.png","7.png"];

var cnt=1;
$("img").click(function{
  //If last image then reset to first image
  if(cnt==imagesToShow.length){
     cnt=0;  
  }
  var nextimage="images/Delivery/"+imagesToShow[cnt];
  $(this).attr("src",nextimage);  

  cnt++;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can make it simply by passing class in for loop...No need to write big js